# Capturing the selected item of select tag in multiple select tags with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am using a django framework where in, i am sending a list from python backend via render to response to html page so depending upon the condition in list multiple select tags are being created. My question is, i want to fetch or capture the selected value of that dropdown when clicking on the save button which is infront of those dropdowns, but whenever i select the value i am getting the value of first dropdown.
Given here below is my piece of code.

```
    <select style="padding:5px; width:102%;"  onchange="savestate({{result.0}});" 
    class="select11" id="status8" name="status8" title="Choose Status" >

    <option id="status8"  name="status8" >{{result.1}}</option>


    {% if result.1 == "HR_Interview" %}

    <option id="status8"  name="status8">COL</option>


    {% elif result.1 == "Internal_Interview" %}

    <option id="status8"  name="status8">HR_Interview</option>
    <option id="status8"  name="status8">COL</option>


    {% elif result.1 == "COL" %}

    <option id="status8"  name="status8">CS</option>


    {% elif result.1 == "CI" %}

    <option id="status8"  name="status8">CIS</option>


    {% elif result.1 == "CIS" %}

    <option id="status8"  name="status8">Joining</option>



    {% elif result.1 == "CS" %}

    <option id="status8"  name="status8">CI</option>


    {% elif result.1 == "Line_up" %}

    <option id="status8"  name="status8">Internal_Interview</option>
    <option id="status8"  name="status8">HR_Interview</option>
    <option id="status8"  name="status8">COL</option>

    {% else %}   



    {% endif %}

    </select> 
    <input class="css_save1" type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onclick = "function9({{result.1}});"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value={{name}}>

<script>
    function function9(resume1)
    {
    console.log("input_string:::",resume1);
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!",resume1);
         <!-- var opt1=document.getElementById("status8").value();  -->
        <!-- console.log("input_string:::",opt1); -->
            <!-- var e = document.getElementById("status8"); -->

            <!-- var input_string = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;  -->

         if (resume1 == "COL") 
        <!--if (var input_string.equals("COL"))-->

                {
                var r=confirm("Are you sure?");
                    if (r == true) 
                    {
                    document.getElementById("listOfSearch{{result.0}}").submit();
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                    document.getElementById("listOfSearch{{result.0}}").submit();
                    }
                }
        else
                {
                document.getElementById("listOfSearch{{result.0}}").submit();
                }
        return response;
     }
</script>
```

so the select tag created is in a for loop 
kindly help me with this

Comment: @mplungjan but still i am unable to get the value of selected tags and i need them all in a same id i cant keep the ids unique or distinct

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more about forms, selects and submit

- IDs must be unique! Options do NOT need IDs nor NAMEs.
- NEVER submit a form in the click event of the submit button. Instead use the form's submit event and return true to allow submission, false to stop it

Try this after removing all ID and NAME from your options

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("listOfSearch{{result.0}}").onsubmit=function() {
    var sel = document.getElementById("status8");
    var val = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text; 
    if (val=="COL") return confirm("Are you sure?"); // submit only if confirmed
    return true; // submit anyway if val is not COL
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function function9(x)
    {
    var id = $(x).closest("tr").find('td:eq(1)').find("#status8 option:selected").text();
    console.log("fetched value>>>",id);
}